# Scrape article link then scrape that link to get author in article

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am scraping this link using scrapy--> https://www.japantimes.co.jp/

As you see here in the first image. I am getting the articles on the left. via

[![Check this picture][1]][1]

Once I get this link how do I continue the scrapy to THEN move to the link of the article and then scrape the content in that article. Picture 2?

[image: Here is the content from the HREF link]

Now here is my code.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "japan"
    allowed_domains = ['www.japantimes.co.jp/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.japantimes.co.jp/']

def parse(self, response):
    all_articles = response.xpath('//div[@class ="section_title small single_block"]]')


    for links in all_articles:
        the_link = links.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
```

Now that I have the links how do I THEN scrape the data in each link?

Answer (score 2):

To have your spider make new requests, you will need to `yield` a `Request` object to the scrapy's engine.

```
from scrapy import Request
...
yield Request(url=URL_OF_THE_PAGE, callback=CALLBACK_PARSE_FUNCTION)
```

[Read more here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

However, in your case you should make sure there is an URL inside the `the_link` variable. Once you fix that, check that the url is an absolute url, if it isn't you can use `response.urljoin(the_link)` to build the url using your response url as base domain.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. however when I call yield Request(url=URL_OF_THE_PAGE, callback=CALLBACK_PARSE_FUNCTION) in my for loop, itgoes to the callback function sending the same link over and over. It does not show all the different links. When I look at my .json file it only went through the first link, not all of them.

Comment: You can create a new function to parse this request, and pass that function in the callback parameter of the request.